# What does Quirt's Summer Stash in Dota 2 contain?

Tags: dota-2

I recently got a **Quirt's Summer Stash Treasure Box** in Dota 2, but when I select **'Peek Inside'**, it doesn't show me what I'll get!

[image: Quirt's Summer Stash]

So the question is, **does anyone know what does 'Quirt's Summer Stash' contain**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per its tooltip, [Quirt's Summer Stash](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Treasure_Chests#Series_.2333_-_Quirt.27s_Summer_Stash) contains one of the following items:

- [Flying Desolation](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Flying_Desolation)
- [Twin Serpent Bow](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Twin_Serpent_Bow)
- [Raven Scythe](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Raven_Scythe)
- [Headdress of the Protector](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Headdress_of_the_Protector)
- [Wavecutter](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Wavecutter)
- [Evildoer](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Evildoer)
- [Aghanim's Basher](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Aghanim's_Basher)
- [Nature's Grip](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Nature's_Grip)
- [Meat Dragger](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Meat_Dragger)
- [Stone Infusion](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Stone_Infusion)
- [Shadowshards](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Shadowshards)
- [Spine Splitter](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Spine_Splitter)
- [or an Exceedingly Rare Special Item!](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Unusual) (that is, an Unusual quality Courier)

*The links lead to the Dota 2 Wiki (a Gamepedia subwiki) and feature images and descriptions of the various items.*

Comment: Added as an answer as the asker [apparently also wants pictures and data on the items](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/125700/).

Comment: awesome. very detailed post!

Answer (score 1):

Well after hovering on the treasure box icon for a bit, I actually found this:

[image: Quirt's Summer Stash Reveal]

Here are the list of items you can get :

```
Flying Desolation
Twin Serpent Bow
Raven Scythe
Headdress of the Protector
Wavecutter
Evildoer
Aghanim's Basher
Nature's Grip
Meat Dragger
Stone Infusion
Shadowshards
Spine Splitter
or an Exceedingly Rare Special Item!
```

Still, it doesn't show you the item icons of what you might get, it just displays the items in words, unlike the other chests...